# How to Add Admin Level Authorization for Azure Java Functions

Tags: azure-functions, postman, azure-java-sdk, azure-http-trigger

I've Created HttpTrigger Azure Java Functions,
Function Name
1.ADMIN (ADMIN LEVEL Authherization)

[image]

Above Function Having Admin Auth, Successfully Deployed to Function app
and I've Updated _master Key Value In Function App

[image]

But, This Function Not Working In Postman Even I use Master key and Value In Autherization Section Through Postman

[image]

Postman Error: 404Not Found

Please Guide me is it right way to use Admin Auth For  azure Java Function or need to ADD/change any Things in Code/Function App Level?

Comment: Please post your code in text/code format, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization keys for the Azure Function App Function URL should be passed in the Headers section like:

[image]

and the Input parameters to the Azure Functions URL should be passed in the params section like below:

[image]

#### Updated Answer

1. Admin Level Authorization Http Trigger Function
2. Changed its master key value to "goodmorning"

**Function Run in Postman with that admin authorization key-value**:

[image]

Comment: Hi Hari, I did Same.... I added Same Header in different way from Autherization section

Comment: Pass the authorization key in headers section as I have shown, not in the form of API Key in the Authorization Section.

Comment: Hari I did that but same Result

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of postman how you are doing/passing the parameters?

Comment: krishna Your Solution Not working.... I think you are Invoking Anonymous Function with Header

Comment: @Balu, updated the screen recording regarding the admin level authorization function's master value updated with the given value "goodmorning" and tested in postman